# Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found. in mac android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Actually I import project in android studio and after that run this project then it gives error

> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

I am using volley library and also fabrics

I am new to android studio so please help to resolve this issue

My build.gradle file is

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
 }
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


  android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.rozgari.techequity.rozgari'
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 12
    versionName '2.0.0'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
compile project(':volley')
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
  }

 crashlytics {
enableNdk true
androidNdkOut 'src/main/obj'
androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/libs'
}
```

top level build file is

```
  buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
 }
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they          belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include standard repositories.

You need to organize your repositories section like this:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

And you can always use [GitHub sources search](https://github.com/search?q=https%3A%2F%2Fmaven.fabric.io%2Fpublic&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) to view how other people use Fabric.